# PHP associate arrays and user inputs having trouble

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a project for my class. We never went over arrays and i am trying to figure out how to use an associate on with user inputs. I have no idea if I am on the right track. I will eventually need to sort my array with key values. But first off it would be great if I could get some feedback on what I have here. I keep getting an error message ": syntax error, unexpected 'each' (T_STRING), expecting "

And i even getting the values for my array correctly and associating them with the array?
I struggle with arrays. I am also new to php.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Student Form</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="final_project.php">
<P>Please enter your name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtname" SIZE= 10></P>
<P>Please enter your id: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtid" SIZE= 10></P>
<P>Please enter your address: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtaddress" SIZE= 10></P>
<P>Please enter your cell phone number: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtcell" SIZE= 10></P>
<P>Please enter your Major: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtmajor" SIZE= 10></P>
<P>Please enter your E-mail address: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtemail" SIZE= 10></P>
<P><INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="submit" VALUE="Submit"></P>
</FORM>
<?php
$txtname = $_POST['txtname'];
$txtid = $_POST['txtid'];
$txtaddress = $_POST['txtaddress'];
$txtcell = $_POST['txtcell'];

$array = array(txtname=>$txtname, txtid=>$txtid, txtaddress=>$txtaddress, txtcell=>$txtcell);
for each ($txtid as $key => $array){
echo "Your first name is ".$txtname.", id number is ".$txtid[$key].", your address is ".$txtaddress.", phone number is ".$txtcell.".";
}
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thanks

Comment: remove the space between for and each

Answer (score 1):

Your scripts contain syntax error,  ***for each***  should be ***foreach*** . Array index txtname should be 'txtname' and so on. 
Finally in foreach you have used a variable not an array. I think it should be an array ($array). Change your scripts

**From**

```
$array = array(txtname=>$txtname, txtid=>$txtid, txtaddress=>$txtaddress, txtcell=>$txtcell);
for each ($txtid as $key => $array){
    echo "Your first name is ".$txtname.", id number is ".$txtid[$key].", your address is ".$txtaddress.", phone number is ".$txtcell.".";
}
```

**to**

```
$array = array('txtname'=>$txtname, 'txtid'=>$txtid, 'txtaddress'=>$txtaddress, 'txtcell'=>$txtcell);
foreach ($array as $value){
    echo $value.'</br>';
}
```

Comment: also might be a good idea to check if the posts are set before trying to echo anything

Comment: In this case `$value` will not be an array. `$value` will be the first record or `$array['txtname']`. `$value['txtname']`, `$value['txtid']`, `$value['txtaddress']` and `$value['txtcell']` will be undefined. Remember that `foreach` iterates through each row in the array. For your code to work, `$array` would need to be a multi-dimensional array...

Answer (score 0):

There's a few modifications you should consider. It's a good idea to check the `$_POST` values to ensure that they exist before trying to use them. It's also a good idea to sanitize any user input you receive to make sure you protect yourself from possible malicious content. Finally, if you save the posted values with the field names, you can reference them easily to create a sentence without having to loop through the array using `for`, `foreach`, `while` or `do-while`.

```
<?php
/*
 * Array contains the desired fields. You could add txtmajor or txtemail
 * for example in the future if you desire. This is an additional safety
 * check as well. You should never blindly save all $_POST fields as a
 * user with malicious intent or a third party may have modified the
 * initial request to contain extra data.
 */
$fields = array("txtname", "txtid", "txtaddress", "txtcell");

// Ensure this was a POST request and not the initial GET request.
if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "post") {
    // Create an array to store the posted values
    $values = array();

    /*
     * Loop through the $fields array you created above and make sure
     * the post array contains the key. This will ensure that you don't
     * leave a required field out or make a typo in your HTML.
     */
    foreach($fields as $value) {

        /*
         * If the key exists and the value was not left blank, strip it
         * for any malicious tags, trim off leading and trailing white
         * space and save it in your $values array with the field name
         * as the key. This makes it easy to reference the value in the
         * future.
         *
         * Note: This is minimal sanitation. You should always take
         *       check your user's input especially if you plan to 
         *       redisplay it on the screen at a later time or store
         *       it in a database.
         */
        if(array_key_exists($value, $_POST) && !empty($_POST[$value])) {
            $values[$value] = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$value]));
        } else {

            /*
             * If the key doesn't exist, there may be a typo in your HTML
             * or the returned content may have been manipulated by a third
             * party person, proxy or service. Whatever the case, kill the
             * script and render the plain HTML.
             */
            exit;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Finally, since you know the field names and you want to use the
     * information in a single sentence, there's no point in looping back
     * through the array. Reference the values and echo the sentence...
     */
    echo "Your first name is " . $values['txtname'] . ", id number is " . $values['txtid'] . ", your address is " . $values['txtaddress'] . ", phone number is " . $values['txtcell'] . ".";
}
?>
```